Obtaining mean effect size estimates and confidence intervals when a factor level combination is missing
I fitted a model using the metafor package with a moderator interaction for which there is no data for a combination of factor levels.
library(orchaRd)
data(fish)
warm_dat <- fish
warm_dat$factor2<-as.factor(seq(c("A","B","C"),133) )

mod_fit <- metafor::rma.mv(yi = lnrr, V = lnrr_vi,
random = list(~1 | group_ID, ~1 | es_ID),
mods = ~ trait.type*factor2,
method = "REML", test = "t",
control=list(optimizer="optim", optmethod="Nelder-Mead"), data = warm_dat)

I wanted to use the orchaRd package to obtain mean effect sizes and confidence intervals but I get an error.
results1 <- mod_results(mod_fit, group = "group_ID", mod = "trait.type", by = "Measurement_cat")
results2 <- mod_results(mod_fit, group = "group_ID", mod = "trait.type")


Error in ref_grid(result, ...) : Something went wrong:
Non-conformable elements in reference grid.

I had a look at the code used in mod_results and found that it relies on emmeans. I tried to adapt the code by manually adding the missing combination of factor levels to the reference grid but the results I obtained were identical to estimates provided by the summary function.
coef1<-mod_fit$b
coef1[12]<-NA
names(coef1)<-c(row.names(mod_fit$b),"trait.typelife-history:factor2C")
vcov1<-stats::vcov(mod_fit)
vcov1<- rbind(vcov1,rep(NA, times=11))
vcov1<- cbind(vcov1,rep(NA, times=12))
row.names(vcov1)<-c(row.names(vcov(mod_fit)),"trait.typelife-history:factor2C")
colnames(vcov1)<-row.names(vcov1)

 grid <- emmeans::qdrg(formula =  stats::formula(mod_fit), 
       data = warm_dat, coef = coef1, vcov = vcov1, 
      df = mod_fit$k - 1)
    mm <- emmeans::emmeans(grid, specs =~trait.type * factor2, df = as.numeric(mod_fit$ddf[[1]]))
    mm_pi <- pred_interval_esmeans(mod_fit, mm, mod = trait.type)

Any suggestions as to how to obtain estimates and confidnece intervals in this instance would be much appreciated.

If you have missing cells, that creates non-estimability issue, and it seems possible that this situation is not being handled correctly by the metafor package.  It may be useful to try to report this issue to that package's website. Also, you may gain some insight by trying a different packag (maybe glmmTMB or nlme?) which can fit something reasonably close to what you need.

More specifically, some package developers just throw out some columns of the X matrix; but to handle non-estimability correctly, you have to keep those columns and recognize that "throwing out" a column is actually a way of constraining its regression coefficient to be zero. If you look at the column names of model_matrix(formula(mod_fit), data=warm_dat), and compare those to the names of your model coefficients, you might be able to cobble together a new complete set of coefficients, and set the coefs for the excluded ones to NA. Then it might work.

Yes, I will agree that in the long run it might be better if glmmTMB filled in NA values for the missing/non-identifiable parameters.  Not something we've gotten around to -  one could open an issue ...

@BenBolker Not a problem, now that we have working emmeans support for glmmTMB models (and also merMod). It uses similar code to what I suggest here to fill-in the missing values where they are needed. So not planning to create an issue...

Following my 2nd comment, I think you may kind of have things backwards, in that you are setting some estimates you need to NA rather than creating a longer list of coefficients that includes NAs. Try something like this:
X = model.matrix(stats::formula(mod_fit), data = warm_dat)
b = mod_fit$b
full.coef = X[1, ] * NA   # a bunch of NAs with the right names
full.coef[names(b)] = b   # so now full.coef has NAs only where excluded from b
grid <- emmeans::qdrg(formula =  stats::formula(mod_fit), 
       data = warm_dat, coef = full.coef, vcov = vcov(mod_fit), 
      df = mod_fit$k - 1)
# etc.

Note that the vcov part is supposed to be the incomplete version with rows and columns dropped.
Update
The code in the OP does not quite work right. So for factor2 I used
warm_dat$factor2 = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], 137))[1:410]

The fix I proposed almost works. But an additional issue is that the intercept is named intrcpt instead of the conventional (Intercept) returned by model.matrix. (What's so wrong with package developers following established conventions???) Anyway this necessitates an additional line of code to set the intercept.
So below is the result I obtain. Note that the second element is correctly flagged as non-estimable.
data(fish, package="orchaRd")
warm_dat <- fish
warm_dat$factor2 = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], 137))[1:410]
mod_fit <- metafor::rma.mv(yi = lnrr, V = lnrr_vi,
                           random = list(~1 | group_ID, ~1 | es_ID),
                           mods = ~ trait.type*factor2,
                           method = "REML", test = "t",
                           control=list(optimizer="optim", optmethod="Nelder-Mead"), data = warm_dat)
## Warning: Redundant predictors dropped from the model.


library(emmeans)

b = mod_fit$b
full.coef = NA * model.matrix(stats::formula(mod_fit), data = warm_dat)[1, ]
full.coef[rownames(b)] = b   # so now full.coef has NAs only where excluded from b
full.coef[1] = b[1]       # needed because of unconventional naming of the intercept
RG <- emmeans::qdrg(formula =  stats::formula(mod_fit), 
                      data = warm_dat, coef = full.coef, vcov = vcov(mod_fit), 
                      df = mod_fit$k - 1)
confint(RG)
##  trait.type   factor2 prediction     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
##  behaviour    A         0.953537 0.2992 409   0.3654   1.5417
##  life-history A           nonEst     NA  NA       NA       NA
##  morphology   A         0.001582 0.0224 409  -0.0425   0.0456
##  physiology   A         0.038965 0.0454 409  -0.0502   0.1282
##  behaviour    B        -0.028576 0.1827 409  -0.3878   0.3306
##  life-history B         0.444830 0.1296 409   0.1901   0.6995
##  morphology   B         0.004905 0.0226 409  -0.0394   0.0492
##  physiology   B        -0.000301 0.0467 409  -0.0922   0.0916
##  behaviour    C         0.057822 0.1889 409  -0.3135   0.4291
##  life-history C         0.972144 0.1695 409   0.6389   1.3054
##  morphology   C        -0.004610 0.0234 409  -0.0507   0.0415
##  physiology   C         0.004195 0.0404 409  -0.0752   0.0836
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95

Created on 2024-07-26 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you sor taking the time to propose a solution. It works if I change names(b) to rownames(b).  However I cannot get the summary of the emmeans object:
 summary(mm)```

@cosalofa is that fish dataset available in an R package -- or publicly available somewhere? It'd be helpful to have a reproducible example.

I can see fish data sets in some packages I have installed, but none of them have variable names matching those used in the example: pp <- help.search("^fish$", agrep = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE)$matches$Package;  for (p in pp) { cat(p, "\n"); data("fish", package = p); print(names(fish)); rm("fish") }

Apologies, I forgot to add the package in which it is found (orchaRd). I have modified the initial post to include this.

I am still unable to reproduce the analysis, because the line warm_dat$factor2<-as.factor(seq(c("A","B","C"),133) ) throws an error -- invalid use of seq(). And I could guess rep(c("A","B","C"),133)" except that warm_dat has 410 rows and 3*133 = 399. So could you give us the actual code you used, and test it first?

Sorry about that, I copied the code from R the first time and it worked. I must have manipulated the dataset beforehand. I see that you have updated your solution. It works perfectly now, thank you very much!

@cosalofa I also added a reference to this posting to an earlier issue I had posted on metafor's site, and maybe the developer will improve this functionality accordingly.
